# Debian Package Creation- how to define environment variables within the package

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, packaging

I built a package with the sudo-ldap package defined as a dependency in the control file (please see below).  I'm going to have people install using the gdebi command to install which should install the package and any required dependencies.  Unfortunately, this will require the export SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes variables to be set or the sudo-ldap package will not be installed and will error out the entire package install.  How do I define an environment variable for the whole package creation.  My ultimate goal is to have a user install this package without having to manually define environment variables...I know I can call this package with a script, but I'd rather not do that.

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends} ldap-utils,sudo-ldap
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions...pretty please with a cherry on top :).  I want to have an unattended install without having to put in any shell environment variables before installing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is two debs. The first one lobotomises sudo's `prerm` script. The second one depends on `sudo-ldap`. This approach wouldn't work with APT (installing both in one run) because there's no guarantee that the lobotomisation package would be installed first. However, if driven through gdebi, it should work.

Do you actually need `sudo-ldap`? Normal `sudo` works with LDAP, it just doesn't get the `sudoers` configuration from LDAP...

Comment: Hmmm..that's ugly.  Perhaps my less than ideal option for a wrapper script is necessary.  I do need sudo-ldap since we pull sudo information from ldap.   Thanks for the help!